# ngrx entity and multi entity types in state

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have an ngrx state that looks like this:

```
{
  dashboards: Dashboard[];
  selectedDashboard: number
}
```

I have created an entityAdapter for Dashboard and that is working well.  The Dashboard type also contains a list of Widgets.  So I would like to normalize that somehow so that I can just select a widget by id.  I am not sure how to create another entity on the same type though.  I was thinking about adding to the state so it looked like this:

```
{
  dashboards: Dashboard[];
  selectedDashboard: number;
  widgets: Widget[]
}
```

I am running into problems though as it appears I can't create selectors for it unless I make widgets extend EntityState.  For the selectId of the entityAdapter for widget though I would need to use the id in the widget as well.  Is what I am trying to do possible or is my design bad?

Comment: Have you tried declaring the type in your state object `widgets: [key: string]: Widget;`?  This allows you to select by id e.g. `state.widgets[id]`.

Comment: really the only reason I wanted to use entity with it was so that it would take care of turning the array into an object for me.  I went ahead and made a new feature state for widgets.  The problem now is that I am having to keep track of them in two places.  the array in the dashboards state and the actual widgets state.  I am trying to find a way to get dashboards to just link to the widgets state but have not found info on it yet

Answer (score 1):

so what I ended up doing was creating a feature state for widgets.  then the dashboards state just holds an array of keys for the widgets property.  it listens to the same action of widgets but instead of adding the entire thing it just adds the key.  that worked out better since I really just needed it for an ngFor